# Assign unique id, and use as key. asp.net mvc model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

Im creating a signup form with ASP.NET MVC, where I want to assign an ID to each new entry, and use this as the primary key.

I've started creating my model with first name, last name, phone etc.

So my question is how do I write this in my model?

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Field is missing")]
[StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 1)]
public string FirstName { get; set; }

....

[Key]
When new entry is created, assign a Unique ID.
```

Or is this something that should be fixed by controllers, and one can just create a key and a "int PersonID" for example?

Comment: Why aren't you using builtin Identity framework? that should handle all of this. anyway, with custom model, you could use GUID as key and assign new guid to key on constructor.

Comment: I'm trying to write as much as possible myself, for learning purposes :) Ok, I will try reading up on GUID. Thank you

Comment: You can mark your property with `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`. See [this](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/databasegenerated-dataannotations-attribute.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use Database first method you can define Id integer and set Is Identity = Yes
so the database automatically increment Id. on this method you can define Id Like this:

```
public string Id { get; set; }
```

or if you want to use Code first method :

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;


[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```